# MinGW screw up with COLORREF and RGB

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I am trying to build a 3rd party open source project using MinGW. One of the dependencies is wxWidgets. When I try to make the project from MSYS I get a compiler error from

`/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-2.8/wx/msw/private.h`

```
In function 'COLORREF wxColourToRGB(const wxColour&)':
error: cannot convert 'RGB' to 'COLORREF {aka long unsigned int}' in return
```

This is somewhat odd given that, [according to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the `RGB` macro returns a `COLORREF`.

In fact, looking in H:\MinGW\include I find wingdi.h with the following code

```
#define RGB(r,g,b) ((COLORREF)((BYTE)(r)|((BYTE)(g) << 8)|((BYTE)(b) << 16)))
```

What sort of thing would cause this error? Is there some way I can check to see if COLORREF and RGB are being included from wingdi.h and not somewhere else? Is that even worth checking?

**Specifications**

- GCC version 4.7.2
- wxWidgets version 2.8.12

(I'm new to C++ and MinGW specifically but generally computer and programming literate)

Comment: What compiler version are you using?

Comment: The MinGW version I'm using came with GCC 4.7.2. I've added this information to the original post.

Comment: Somebody swallowed the t from int.

Comment: Fixed. I can't copy from the msys shell, or at least I don't know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try preprocessing the source with `-E` and check what is actually happening with the macro expansion or whether something is redefining the macro.

The preprocessed source undoubtedly will be very lengthy after `#include`ing its header dependencies. Your text editor's search function, `grep` and `findstr` are your friends here.

Comment: I did this and can see that RGB is not being expanded. This must mean that something is messing with it...

Comment: @kjoppy In the preprocessed sourced you should also see comment hints on the header file name and line#. Do you see `wingdi.h` anywhere there? You can goto that line where RGB is supposely defined and see where it went. Did something else undefine it later on or perhaps an `ifdef` guard cutted it out?

Comment: This was a good suggestion. I found that the supposed RGB macro wasn't being expanded. I then finally found that it was being #undefed in one of the project's headers because the original author wanted the name for a 3 byte struct. I just renamed `RGB` to `RGB3` everywhere in the project's source, removed the `#undef RGB` line, and everything's hunky-dory.

Comment: @kjoppy and this is why macros are evil ;)

Comment: That sounds like the sort of statement that I simply won't appreciate until it's too late...